# How to add custom tag to default metrics using opentelemetry collector and opentelemetry Java agent

Tags: metrics, open-telemetry, custom-tags

I have a Spring Boot plugin which has 3 custom metrics connected to a main microservice and I have already exposed its metrics with the help of OpenTelemtry collector and OpenTelemtry Java agent. But the issue is that I need to add custom tags to the generated default metrics in OpenTelemtry. Is there any solution for this?

[image: exposed metrics image]
[image: custom metrics image]]
[image: dependency image]

I tried the solutions present in
[Sumologic docs](https://help.sumologic.com/docs/apm/traces/get-started-transaction-tracing/opentelemetry-instrumentation/java/custom-tags-configuration/) but it didn't work for me, and the custom tag configuration through your code option isn't specified enough.

Comment: Do you need these custom tags to come from the application? Otherwise you could add them in the collector pipeline itself.

Comment: @julealgon I am using the optentelemetry collector and in the spring boot i am using opentelemetry as a dependency.
Can i get directions to either of the solution?

Comment: @julealgon if we were to add custom tags to come through from the application, what will be the process for it?

Comment: Usually, each instrumentation library/plugin offers you a way to "enrich" the data. This is what most of the .NET instrumentations provide. Otherwise, I think you need to rely on the base "processor" abstraction from the OpenTelemetry SDK. That's a lower level integration though and I've personally not used that yet so I can't quite guide you on it. It is also possible to provide extra attributes via common OTEL environment variables, but those would of course usually come from outside the application as well.

Answer (score 3):

If the attributes are not dependent on the specific application, you can add them through the collector itself.

Here is an example that adds the "deployment.environment" standard attribute to every telemetry passing through the collector (imagine this is your "staging collector", in this example):

```yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:

processors:
  batch:
    timeout: 10s

  resource:
    attributes:
    - key: deployment.environment
      value: "staging"
      action: upsert

exporters:
  datadog:
    api:
      key: ${DATADOG_APIKEY}

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [resource, batch]
      exporters: [datadog]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [resource, batch]
      exporters: [datadog]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [resource, batch]
      exporters: [datadog]
```

You can look at the documentation for the "resource" processor here:

- [OpenTelemetry Collector - Resource Processor](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/resourceprocessor)

Comment: Hi @julealgon,
thanks for your solution and I tried it, but there were no attributes shown from the metrics generated from the OpenTelemetry Collector.

Comment: That's weird @GavinFernando. This file that I shared is almost identical to our actual production yaml configuration file and it is working fine to add the environment variable to everything that we push. Perhaps you can double check your collector version and configuration? Did you add the processor to the pipelines? Notice how you not only need to define the processor in the beginning, but also have to mention it explicitly on each pipeline in the "processors" property. If you don't, it will just be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

When you add `spring-boot-starter-actuator` to your project, by default, you have `http_server_requests_second_count` and a lot of other useful metrics published on the endpoint `.../actuator/prometheus`.

Here are two places where you can add your metrics if it fits your use-case:

- Assuming you are using actuator, in your spring boot app, put in the property file:

```
management:
  metrics:
    tags:
      custom_metric: value
```

For example, you may want to add a tag that represent the environment where your app is running.
**application.qa.yml:**

```
management:
  metrics:
    tags:
      environment: dev
```

**application.preprod.yml**:

```
management:
  metrics:
    tags:
      environment: preprod
```

- You can add it inside the opentelemetry-collector configuration. For that, you have to use **opentelemetry-collector-contrib** not the base opentelemetry-collector. (removed unnecessary configs)

```
receivers:
  ...
  

processors:
  metricstransform:
    transform:
      - include: .*
        match_type: regexp
        action: update
        operations:
          - action: add_label
            new_label: environment
            new_value: preprod
  batch:

exporters:
  ...

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      ...

    metrics:
      ...
      processors: [metricstransform, batch]
      ...
```